How to use JWT authentication in Trino?
I am setting up JWT authentication using a file; how can I implement this?

I know that I have to add to the config.properties file the lines:
http-server.authentication.type=JWT and
http-server.authentication.jwt.key-file=path_file
And now, how can I add users in the PEM or HMAC file?

